# Safari Power Save ... new on Maverick update ... how do I hide this?

Tags: flash, safari

We're now starting to see a message pop up, "Safari Power Save" on Mac OS Maverick's newest Safari update and we don't know how to disable/hide it:

http://screencast.com/t/g3x3ZQsAtHtz

We've got a page with using Wistia's video player (http://wistia.com/) which uses flash to play video.  They're on a desktop (not iPad) and getting the message above which is a bit of an eyesore on the page.  We've got this HTML on the page: http://snipt.org/AjhK3

Anyway to hide/disable the "Safari Power Save" message that's showing up?

Answer (score 0):

That can be turned off in advanced preferences or specific websites allowed in by turning it on for the specific player on the website with a single click.  Apparently there isn't any way for the content provider to turn it on a users computer.  (I'm glad of that.  I hate losing any control of my computer to anyone else.)   Apparently, the software doesn't prevent things like a Youtube video because it's part of the page you wanted to view anyway.  So even though I've had Mavericks loaded up since day one, I just saw Safari Power saver for the first time today.  (That's one week of use without ever seeing it.)   I fully intend to leave it running on my machine and will only activate specific flash videos only where it meets my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to `Safari` -> `Preferences` -> `Advanced` -

Untick - Stop Plug-Ins to Save Power. That should do the trick.

I just started getting it too.